# how to do dynamic divs - expand collapse loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I need a function that allows my client to add more divs on the form or not, clicking on a button (+) for example, like a loop

this loop should repet divs and the button to add more divs, like bellow on the pic

[image]

does anybody has an ideia of how to do it?

is expand collapse the best way of doing it?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Basically this is easy but how do you want to handle headlines? / Fielddescription? Do you just want to expand them or shall they be created new?

Comment: *does anybody has an ideia of how to do it?* We do have idea. It is important for us to know that do you have an idea. Show us

Comment: @Steini hi, when clicking on the button, it should create new

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not certain what is your desire so I post both options:

If you want to expand hidden existing fields and asuming you can use JQUery:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Field1</th>
        <td><input type="text" value="" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>Field2</th>
        <td><input type="text" value="" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="hiddenarea" style="display: none;">
        <th>Field3 (Hidden)</th>
        <td><input type="text" value="" /></td>
    </tr>
</table>
<input id="show_hide" value="Collapse/Expand" />

<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#show_hide").click(function() {
        $(".hiddenarea").toggle();
    });
</script>
```

///////////////////////////////////

The second solution to add a new line to the table is:

```
<table id="mytable">
    <tr>
        <th>Field1</th>
        <td><input type="text" value="" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>Field2</th>
        <td><input type="text" value="" /></td>
    </tr>
</table>
<input id="show_hide" value="Collapse/Expand" />

<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#show_hide").click(function() {
        $("#mytable").append('<tr><td>New field</td><td><input type="text" value="" /></td></tr>');
    });
</script>
```